# tcpdf: convert html table to pdf

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <?php
                                                                    
        function fetch_data(){
            $output = '';
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "something");
            $ID = $_COOKIE['ID'];

            $sql_0 = "SELECT users.name, leave_form.type_of_leave, leave_form.application_date,leave_form.leave_days,  
                                leave_form.starting_date,leave_form.end_date,leave_form.reporting_date ,leave_form.Approval FROM users,leave_form WHERE
                                    users.ID=leave_form.ID && leave_form.Approval='Denied' ";
                                    
                                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_0);

                                    
                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                        $output .='
                                        <form method="POST" action="../auth/processes.php">
                                        <tr><td><input type="text" value= '.$row["name"].' readonly class="form-control"/></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" value="'.$row["type_of_leave"].'" readonly class="form-control"/></td>
                                        <td><input type="timestamp" value="'.$row["application_date"]. '" readonly class="form-control"/></td>
                                        <td><input type="number" value="'.$row["leave_days"].'" readonly class="form-control"/></td>
                                        <td><input type="date" value="'.$row["starting_date"].'" readonly class="form-control"/></td>
                                        <td><input type="date" value="'.$row["end_date"]. '" readonly class="form-control"/></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" value="'.$row["Approval"]. '" readonly class="form-control"/></td>
                                        <td><a href="../auth/authenticate.php"><img src="../assets/images/send.png" alt="post" height="40px"/></a></td></tr></form>
                                        </form>';
                                    }
                                    return $output;
                                    
                                }
                                if(isset($_POST["generate_pdf"])){
                                    require_once('../tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
                                    $obj_pdf = new TCPDF ('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
                                    $obj_pdf -> SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
                                    $obj_pdf -> SetTitle("My first pdf");
                                    $obj_pdf -> SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
                                    $obj_pdf -> SetHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
                                    $obj_pdf -> SetFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
                                    $obj_pdf -> SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');
                                    $obj_pdf -> SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
                                    $obj_pdf -> SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '10', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
                                    $obj_pdf -> setPrintHeader(false);
                                    $obj_pdf -> setPrintFooter(false);
                                    $obj_pdf -> setAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);
                                    $obj_pdf -> SetFont('helvetica', '', 11); 
                                    $obj_pdf -> AddPage();
                                    $content = '';
                                    $content .= '
                                    
                                    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th width = "14.28%" >Name</th>
                                            <th width = "14.28%" >Type of Leave</th>
                                            <th width = "14.28%" >Application Date</th>
                                            <th width = "14.28%" >Leave Days</th>
                                            <th width = "14.28%" >Starting Date</th>
                                            <th width = "14.28%" >End Date</th>
                                            <th width = "14.28%" >Approval</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    ';
                                    $content .= fetch_data();
                                    $content .= '</table>';
                                    $obj_pdf -> writeHTML($content);
                                    $obj_pdf -> Output('file.pdf', 'I');
                                }
        ?>
    <div class="col-md-12" align="right">
        <form method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="generate_pdf" value="Generate PDF"/>
        </form>
    <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered troom">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Applicant Name</th>
            <th>Type of Leave</th>
            <th>Application Date</th>
            <th>Days Applied For</th>
            <th>Starting Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
            <th>Approval</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        echo fetch_data();
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
                            
</body>
</html>
```

**the above code generates the following error when trying to convert my html table to a pdf: Any assistance will be helpful**

> Notice: Undefined index: rows in C:\xampp\htdocs\novel\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 16916
>
> Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\novel\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 16918
>
> Notice: Undefined index: thead in C:\xampp\htdocs\novel\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 16498
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'url' in C:\xampp\htdocs\novel\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 18807
>
> Notice: Undefined index: trids in C:\xampp\htdocs\novel\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19478
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\novel\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19478
>
> Notice: Undefined index: trids in C:\xampp\htdocs\novel\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19507
>
> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\novel\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19507
>
> Notice: Undefined index: trids in C:\xampp\htdocs\novel\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19510
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\novel\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19510
>
> Notice: Undefined index: old_cell_padding in C:\xampp\htdocs\novel\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19720
>
> TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Answer (score 0):

One of the major issues I see is that you are outputting HTML to the page even when you want to be generating a PDF. That is the cause of this error:

> TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

You can test this by going to the TCPDF examples and inserting text or HTML elements at the start or end of the file.